# Quiero extraer información con el método get pero sin definir variable

Tags: php

Me explico, para hacer un API tradicional lo que hago es `/API/?data=123 ($_GET['data'])`

Lo que yo quiero hacer es solo hacer `/API/123`, solo quiero extraer la información de acuerdo a lo que esté en el path

Uso php, estaría agradecido que me ayudaran

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: no es recomendable y es poco escalable

Comment: por que motivo crees que es buena idea o quieres usar o implementar algo asi???

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: No necesito más variables, esa sería la búsqueda en una base de datos y al ingresar a la página le daría el resultado, así de simple, si fuera para algo más elaborado obvio no lo haría así, y claro, utilizaría otros métodos más recomendables, esto lo hago para que cualquiera que quiera pueda hacerlo sin saber mucho, o sea, no estar poniendo los "?"+nombre variable+=+la consulta

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es dividir el path y coger la opción donde se encuentra el valor.

En este caso al ser el último elemento de la ruta el código podría quedar así:

```
value = end(explode('/', getenv('REQUEST_URI')));
```

Si además la url tiene parámetros, tienes que acordarte de eliminarlos:

```
value = end(explode('/', strtok(getenv('REQUEST_URI'), '?')));
```

Comment: no es recomendable y es poco escalable

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 pues a pesar de todo, ahora mismo es la mejor opción. Quizás aparte de votar negativo y hacer comentarios que no aportan gran cosa, podrías, tal vez, escribir una respuesta mejor... criticar sin aportar nada parece algo más propio de un troll de la Internet profunda

Comment: No se, dices que no es recomendable pero no he visto nada referente a esas afirmaciones en Internet. De la misma forma que tampoco he encontrado otras alternativas... así que debo insistir, enséñanos (o al menos a mi) cual sería la forma correcta de abordar este problema

Comment: si te percatas ya fue cerrada con la respuesta correcta, lo lamento mucho por ti... y no fui yo el que te metio el voto negativo ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 pues me acabo de dar cuenta. Estoy desde el móvil y la aplicación no se ve igual de bienvenida que desde el ordenador.

Comment: En cualquier caso, tampoco entiendo lo del voto negativo en la pregunta (en la respuesta tampoco, ya que técnicamente es válida). Somos un poco intransigentes y luego lloramos porque el sitio no termina de atraer talento en cantidad...

Comment: dudo que el sitio este buscando "talentos" que no quieran seguir las normas del sitio, estoy casi seguro que los votos negativos son por no seguir las normas del sitio... suele pasar... y no tiene nada que ver con actitudes de la comunidad mejor dicho tiene que ver con las actitudes de los que preguntan y responden ...